# Artefacts appearing on website: CSS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been stumped by this for a bit and would really appreciate some advice if possible. So here is the offending website in question: [Imran Ahmed's Website](http://imranahmed.io)

The issue that I'm having is with these buttons: [image: Buttons] In the example above, the 'Devpost' button shouldn't just appear by itself, it should also have another button 'Github' next to it (as shown in the image below). [image: Ideal]

Now, while the div for this is in the correct place, the button actually appears right at the top of the screen (as an artefact) here: 
[image: Error]

This is obviously not the correct functionality for the website. In terms of things I have tried, I have attempted to change the CSS of the corresponding div (`link-effect`) to use `position: absolute` instead of `position: relative` - while this fixed the artefact, it ruins the button animations (which isn't useful).

Now, one thing I've noticed is that this seems to appear on Chrome only after the slide in animation (part of the WOW package) has finished. If you scroll down to the *My Projects* section and refresh the page you'll notice the button only disappears when the animation completes (here's an example of the formatting working correctly during the middle of the animation):

[image: The page during mid animation]

This leads me to believe there is a change the animation complete function is making that is causing this bug - but unfortunately I can't pinpoint it down. I tried using the chrome animation tool to dive down on the changes but I'm a rookie with web development/debugging and I couldn't make much headway.

With this in mind, I would really appreciate any advice you may have on how to resolve these artefacts! In addition, it would be great if the error could be explained - because I'd like to know how to avoid it in the future! Thanks for everything!

I believe the relevant code in question is below but I'm not exactly sure if this is indeed where the problem lies!

```
.link-effect {
        width: 100%;
        height: 42px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }

.link-effect a {
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: rgba(230, 126, 34, 1);
    position: relative;
    padding: 16px 7px;
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(230, 126, 34, 0);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(230, 126, 34, 0);
    transition: padding .3s, border-color .3s;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.link-effect a::after,
.link-effect a::before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    color: rgba(230, 126, 34, 0);
    content: attr(data-text);
    transition: max-height .3s, border-color 0s
}

.link-effect a:focus,
a:hover {
    padding: 5px 7px;
    border-color: rgba(230, 126, 34, 1);
    outline: 0
}

.link-effect a::before {
    top: 0;
    border-left: 2px solid rgba(230, 126, 34, 0)
}

.link-effect a::after {
    padding: 5px;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(230, 126, 34, 0)
}
```

Comment: a link and images and no code - fail

Comment: @Jaromanda X: More than happy to include the code, I just figured people just viewed it all from the website these days - no matter, one second let me get it up!

Comment: minimal, verifiable and complete example, preferably, not every single line of code :p

Comment: If you expect us to really just inspect the source and work on it, you may as well just give us access to it so we can work on it instead. And pay us while you're at it.

Comment: My apologies, I incorrectly assumed people just had a look at the website. I've uploaded the code I **think** is relevant, but I'm very new to this and I'm not certain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps :)

```
.link-effect {
    width: 100%;
    height: 42px; // remove this
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    display: flex; // add this
    justify-content: center; // add this
}

.link-effect a {
    margin: 0 5px; // change this
    color: rgba(230, 126, 34, 1);
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 7px; // change this
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(230, 126, 34, 0);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(230, 126, 34, 0);
    transition: padding .3s, border-color .3s;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for your response. So I actually had a go at trying this out! Now, the issue that i ran into was that - while I was able to get the buttons in the correct place - the animation stops working (fully) and, for some reason, hovering on one button would trigger the animation for **the other** button (it seems like some unexpected extra padding occurs). Did you not run into this issue?

Comment: I think that is because of the way the animation is implemented. You're using the `padding` on `link-effect a` to adjust the position of the "bars". I would keep the transition to the pseudo-elements. May need to wrap your `<a>`s in another element (a `<div>`?) with `position: relative` to solve the issue and retain the animation.

Comment: This worked (and I didn't even need to change the margin or the padding)! Can I ask what made you realise that this was the issue? How were you able to debug this?

Many thanks for your help Robert - it is much appreciated!

Comment: @ImranAhmed Hey Imran, I don't really know what causes the bug. It was just a gut feeling, that trying another solution could fix it. So basicly try and error :)